# Javascript format date from string to Date format

Tags: javascript, date

how to format a date from a string in the format you want?

```
 var dateString = "31/05/2014 12:53:51";
 // function only accepts dates in the format "yyyy / mm / dd"
 var date = new Date (dateString);
```

Comment: First, parse the string into its constituent parts. Use then in the [*Date constructor*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) to make a date. Then use methods like [*getFullYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10), [*getMonth*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.12), etc. to construct whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function to parse the string in the OP is:

```
// Return a Date object
// Expects string in format d/m/y h:m:s
// Separator is not important, order is
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}
```

or if you just want to reformat the string (I guessed that you don't want the spaces between the numbers and separator):

```
// Return a date in "yyyy / mm / dd" format
// Expects string in format d/m/y h:m:s
// Separator is not important, order is
function reformatDate(s) {
  // Helper to format single digit numbers
  function z(n) {return (n<10? '0' : '') + +n;}
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return b[2] + '/' + z(b[1]) + '/' + z(b[0]);
}
```

The helper function is used just in case single digit numbers aren't padded in the input. If you're confident that they always are, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use some third-party library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Code of your example using moment.js:

```
var date = moment("31/05/2014 12:53:51", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").toDate();
```