# Change dateformat from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm using a Google Form to collect dates from users, they use a datepicker. The format is US with mm/dd/yy (1/25/2016), but i need EU format dd/mm/yy (25/1/2016).

The script collects serval dates:

```
  var Date1 = e.values[24]; 
  var Date2 = e.values[25];
  var Date3 = e.values[26];
  var Date4 = e.values[27];  
  var Date5 = e.values[28];
```

How can i convert these to EU dateformat?

This is what iv'e tried so far without success:

**1)**

```
  function myFunction() {
      var preDate = "1/25/2016";
      var postDate = preDate.Utilities.formatDate(dt, "PST", "dd/mm/yy");
      Logger.log(postDate);
    }
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "formatDate" of undefined.

**2)**

```
function myFunction() {
  var preDate = "1/25/2016"; 
  var postDate = Date.parseExact(preDate ,"dd/MM/yyyy")
  Logger.log(postDate);
}
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot find function parseExact in object function Date() { [native code for Date.Date, arity=1] }

Comment: What is "EU" format? d/m/y is very widely used, not just in countries that are members of the EU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the dates in a Google Spreadsheet, you can use the Utilities.formatDate method to convert dates into another format.

```
function convertDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var source = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  if (typeof source === "date") {
   sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(Utilities.formatDate(dt, "PST", "dd/mm/yy"));
  }
}
```

An easier option would be that you select the entire column in the spreadsheet and the change the default format under the Format menu (see screenshot).

[image: Change Date Format in Spreadsheet]

Comment: Yes but the script fetches the form values, not the values in the spreadsheet for various reasons. As you can see in my example "e.values[26];" = form values.

Comment: The same function can be modified:  
  if (typeof e.values[26] === "date") {
  return Utilities.formatDate(e[26], "PST", "dd/mm/yy"));
  }

Comment: Tried that, i get 'undefined' in the logger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateJS for that, like this:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact

```
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", "M/d/yyyy");  // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parse("15-Oct-2004", "d-MMM-yyyy");    // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parse("2004.10.15", "yyyy.MM.dd");     // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", ["M/d/yyyy", "MMMM d, yyyy"]); // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
```

In your question you need that:

```
Date.parseExact("dateyouneed" ,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Im trying with this without success function myFunction() {
  var Date = "1/25/2016";
  
var newDate = Date.Utilities.formatDate(dt, "PST", "dd/mm/yy");
  
  Logger.log(newDate);

}

Comment: If the intent is to reformat a string, then there is no need for a Date object (or parser) to be involved at all, see [*Javascript format date from string to Date format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308877/javascript-format-date-from-string-to-date-format).